# Grafana dashboard variables do not work in panel queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I created a dashbaord based on Prometheus data source.
I created two variables for the dashboard:

First variable - instance:
Query: query_result(up{job="postgres_exporter"})
Regex: /.*instance="([^"]+).*/

Preview of values shows:
10.97.7.150:9187
10.97.7.97:9187

Second variable - Server:
Query: query_result(pg_settings_port{job="postgres_exporter"})
Regex: /.*server="([^"]+).*/

Preview of values shows:
10.97.7.150:5020
10.97.7.97:5009
10.97.7.97:5020

However, when I try to create a panel with a reference to these 2 variables:
pg_static{instance="$instance", server="$server"}
I get a "N/A" as the result in the panel.

However, if I put the query with hard coded values into the panel, it works. for example:    pg_static{instance="10.97.7.97:9187",job="postgres_exporter",server="10.97.7.97:5009"}
shows the version as expected.

Can any one explain what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When testing variables in a panel did you select only one value for each variable?
If not (so multiple values are selected) then grafana will accommodate that by assuming you will be using expanded variable as a regex and will substitute your variable by something like `10.97.7.150:9187|10.97.7.97:9187`
This is so aregex match can be used. If you want to be able to use multiple values then just use a `=~` operator instead of `=`, so for example:

```
pg_static{instance=~"$instance", server=~"$server"}
```

In general: check out query inspector in grafana to see what exact query is going out

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Do you know if I should make some connection between the 2 variables, so I should put some reference to the "instance" variable in the "server" variable? that is, in order to prevent the end user from choosing a serve which does not belong to the instance?

Comment: @Tamar you absolutely can use one variable in the "query" part of another and in general it will work as expected (changing first variable will cause available values in the second one to be reloaded).